# Add something in, into or on Google Docs?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

What preposition is most suitable referring to the verb *add* and the object *Google Docs*?

> I've just added an essay **in, into** *or* **on** Google Docs?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that it is either on or to (or even onto) depending on what is the perspective of the speaker.

> I've added/put/published the video on YouTube

Is taking the perspective of a certain platform (YouTube/SharePoint/ Google Docs), on which the file is now available

> I've added/moved/transferred the file (on)to the SharePoint

Instead is taking the perspective of the file itself and its journey from the original location to its destination in the cloud

'in' can probably be used too, but I feel that it's better coupled with a different verb, e.g.

> I've put/stored the file in the SharePoint/ a USB pendrive

Conveying the idea of something that is stored for later usage.

Answer (score 0):

to add something to something

as  in a collection of documents or a database of documents

Comment: I don't think that really applies here.  *Google Docs* is the proper name of a site, not literally a collection of documents.

Comment: I agree with stangdon. I can see how you might talk about *adding something to your doc(ument)s*, but that's not how *Google Docs* is really used. But I guess it's not really wrong either because one *might* construe it as a bunch of documents. At any rate, you usually ***upload** a document/whatever to your Google **Drive*** – I'd stick to that phrasing.

Comment: @stangdon I was not commenting on Google Docs per se. Perhaps you should address the OP. Files are uploaded to Google Docs and then converted, as I see it.

Comment: @userr2684291 Google Docs is whatever you put there. A bunch of docs is a collection of docs and you add a document to them. Very simple.